# Restrict image's (or any element's) height to multiple of line height with just HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Been fussing around with grid for a while trying to figure out if this is possible without much luck.

I'm working on a website in which everything is arranged within a strict background grid of 12px square, which is also used as the base font size, so 1rem = 12px. In order to maintain the vertical rhythm, I need to make sure that all elements, including padding and margin and borders, end up with widths and heights at some multiple of that base grid size.

For text content like paragraphs and headings this isn't super difficult, as long as the line heights are all set to 1rem, 2rem, 3rem, etc. For images, however, I struggle to see how to force it to a multiple of the grid size without a bit of javascript.

Not that I *can't* use javascript, but I don't really want to.

So say I have an `<img>` with an original size of 100px by 100px. Is it possible to restrict it to 96px (8rem) or 108px (9rem), or maybe place it within a larger container and enforce the restrictions on the container instead? `grid-auto-rows: 1rem` doesn't seem to do the job (since the element only ever creates 1 implicit track), and neither does `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1rem)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use css @media queries to give your images specific sizes at specific breakpoints.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  img {
    height: 6rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  img {
    height: 7rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  img {
    height: 8rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  img {
    height: 9rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  img {
    height: 10rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  img {
    height: 11rem;
  }
}
```